# javascript how to parse numbers?

Tags: javascript, parsing

Hello so i'm trying to parse numbers that i get once i request page using http web request.But it seems that it fails me  every time :/

Code that i use to make web request and parse:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', "website url", true);
xhr.send();

xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

function processRequest(e) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
       var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          alert(response.);
    }
}
```

I don't know what i need to write after dot i tried many options :(

Example of response that i get:   {"status":1,"request":"1663758118"}

and i need to get only numbers

Html:

```html
<pre>{"status":1,"request":"1663758118"}</pre>
```

So if somebody could help that would be great :)

Comment: "and i need to get only numbers" - What do you mean? What is your desired output?

Comment: use response.request

Comment: this? `JSON.parse(response).request`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, and your code does correctly parse JSON string into JSON object, then you can do the following to retrieve data from JSON object

```
response.status // '1' as int
response.request // "1663758118" as string
```

Hope this answer can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

After dot you need to put the property name in order to get the value.

If you need to convert a string to number you  can add a + sign immediately before the string:

```js
var response = JSON.parse('{"status":1,"request":"1663758118"}');

var stat =  +response["status"];
var req =  +response["request"];

console.log('status is: ' + stat + ' typeof is: ' + typeof stat);
console.log('request is: ' +  req + ' typeof is: ' + typeof req);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need numbers from your response `{"status":1,"request":"1663758118"}`, you can use do this

```js
const response = {"status":1,"request":"1663758118"}
const values = Object.keys(response).map(key => parseInt(response[key], 10))
console.log(values) // => [1, 1663758118]
```